# How format array in php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this code:

```
$id = 1;
$isTemplate = true;
$address = "address, \n tel. 1234455";
```

I need save it in this form:

```
{"results": [{
            "id": 1,
            "isTemplate": true,
            "text": "<span class=\"d-block option-head\">\n    nazwa\n</span>\n<span class=\"d-none\"> - </span>\n<span class=\"d-block option-sub\">\n        address,\n                tel. 123456\n    </span>"
        ]}
```

How can I make it?

I try:

```
$resultArray = array('results' => ['id'=> 1, 'isTemplate' => true, 'text'=> '<span class="d-block option-head">\n    nazwa\n</span>\n<span class="d-none"> - </span>\n<span class="d-block option-sub">\n        address,\n                tel. 1234455\n    </span>']);
```

but my result is wrong:

```
Array
(
    [results] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [isTemplate] => 1
            [text] => <span class="d-block option-head">\n    nazwa\n</span>\n<span class="d-none"> - </span>\n<span class="d-block option-sub">\n        address,\n                tel. 123455\n    </span>
        )

)
```

Please help me

Comment: What is the difference between the output and expected result, it's not so obvious for us.

Comment: Just JSON encode it? `json_encode($resultArray);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$id = 1;
$isTemplate = true;
$address = "address, \n tel. 1234455";

$array = [
    'results' => [
        [
            'id' => $id,
            'isTemplate' => $isTemplate,
            'text' => $address,
        ],
    ],
];

$result = json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

you jus need to add 1 more nesting.

```
$resultArray = ['results' => [['id'=> 1, 'isTemplate' => true, 'text'=> '<span class="d-block option-head">\n    nazwa\n</span>\n<span class="d-none"> - </span>\n<span class="d-block option-sub">\n        address,\n                tel. 1234455\n    </span>']]];

echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_encode($resultArray));
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code lacked a nesting level.

```
$resultArray = array('results' => [
    ['id' => 1, 'isTemplate' => true, 'text' => '<span class="d-block option-head">\n    nazwa\n</span>\n<span class="d-none"> - </span>\n<span class="d-block option-sub">\n        address,\n                tel. 1234455\n    </span>']
]);
var_dump($resultArray, json_encode($resultArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $id = 1;
        $isTemplate = true;
        $address = "address, \n tel. 1234455";
        $text= '<span class="d-block option-head">\n    nazwa\n</span>\n<span class="d-none"> - </span>\n<span class="d-block option-sub">\n        address,\n';
        $array[] = ['id'=>$id ,'isTemplate'=>$isTemplate, 'address' => $address,'text'=>$text];

        $value = json_encode($array);
```

$value will hold the desired result ...